# Ciclos php son sincronos o asincronos?

Tags: php

Tengo un dilema en cuanto a programación:

Estoy recorriendo un array con `foreach` que a su vez esta dentro de un `for` y que contiene un `foreach` mas

```
for ($i=0;$i < 10;$i++){
    foreach($variable as $resp){
        foreach ($variable2 as $key => $value) {
            echo "Esto es solo un ejemplo";
        }
    }
}
```

**Mi pregunta es: todos estos ciclos (for y foreach) se realizan en orden es decir:**

1. Primero ejecutamos el for
2. Luego el primer foreach
3. Luego el tercer foreach

Pero no pasamos al siguiente `item` del `for` si no hemos terminado con el primer `foreach` que a su vez no pasa al siguiente `item` si no termina el segundo `foreach` ?

Se que suena absurda la pregunta pero esto me intriga mucho ya que el segundo `foreach` tiene un `inset mysql` que a veces se lo salta el sistema al recorrer el `array`

Nota: se que no esta definidas las `$variable` y `$variable2` solo puse ese código como referencia (no es real)

Comment: Es como dices. Los foreach que están dentro del for se agotarán primero (ejecutarán no es el término apropiado), y el segundo foreach ($variable2) se agotará antes que el primer foreach. Si el INSERT no funciona debe ser por algún motivo (clave duplicada por ejemplo), eso lo puedes verificar poniendo un control de errores en la consulta SQL. El término síncrono/asíncrono no aplica en este caso.

Comment: gracias @A.Cedano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realmente aquí no aplica intentar hacer una comparación entre síncrono y asíncrono.

Por *síncrono* se entiende una comunicación que ocurre al mismo tiempo, por ejemplo una llamada de teléfono donde el emisor habla y el receptor le responde.

**Asíncrono**, según la RAE, es algo *Que no tiene lugar en completa correspondencia temporal con otro proceso o con la causa que lo produce.* Es decir, el emisor manda el mensaje y la respuesta llega, si llega, cuando el receptor lo recibe, lo lee y lo responde, si quiere y puede (por ejemplo un email, una petición de red, etc). A diferencia de una comunicación síncrona (por ejemplo la llamada de teléfono), en una comunicación asíncrona el receptor no tiene por qué estar ahí al recibir el mensaje (incluso puede estar). Pero la llegada del mensaje y la respuesta dependen de varios factores que hacen que la comunicación no ocurra en tiempo real (lentitud de la red, sobrecarga de los servidores, el receptor está de vacaciones, el mensaje fue a la carpeta de spam y el receptor se dio cuenta 10 días después... etc)

En PHP los bucles (`for` y `foreach`  son bucles), sirven para leer elementos iterables. Y dichos elementos se leen en el orden en que están (a no ser que se indique otra cosa). No hay más.

En tu ejemplo:

- todo lo que esté dentro del primer bucle se repetirá `A` veces donde `A` será el total de iteracciones de dicho bucle
- todo lo que esté dentro del segundo bucle se repetirá `A x B veces`, donde `A` será el número de iteracciones del 1er bucle y `B` el número de iteracciones del 2do bucle, y
- todo lo que esté dentro del tercer bucle se repetirá `A x B x C veces` donde `A` será el número de iteracciones del 1er bucle y `B` el número de iteracciones del 2do bucle y `C` será el número de iteracciones del 3er bucle, así sucesivamente...

Si algo no ocurre en alguna parte de los bucles, no tiene nada que ver con asincronía, a no ser que dentro de alguno de ellos haya algo que dependa de una petición de red o algo así, en que la respuesta dependa de otros factores y tarde en ser recibida.

Si, como dices, hay INSERTs que fallan, eso puede deberse a otros motivos (clave duplicada, violación de alguna restricción, etc). Para ello basta con poner un control de errores en el código para conocer el motivo del fallo.

Reproduciendo tu ejemplo, podemos ver que el código funciona como se ha dicho anteriormente. He puesto un contador al interior de cada bucle, para que se vea con mayor claridad que mientras más interior sea el bucle más repeticiones tendrá, porque se repite todas sus veces multiplicado por las veces de los bucles superiores (observa los totales al final):

```
$totalA=0;
$totalB=0;
$totalC=0;

$variable=array('A','B');
$variable2=array('X','Y','Z');

for ($i=0;$i < 10;$i++){
    $totalA++;
    echo "Primer bucle: $i \n";
    foreach($variable as $resp){
        $totalB++;
        echo "\t Segundo bucle: $resp \n";
        foreach ($variable2 as $key => $value) {
            $totalC++;
            echo "\t\t Tercer bucle: $value \n";
        }
    }
}

echo "--------------\nTOTALES:\n";
echo "1er bucle: $totalA \t10 (su propio bucle) \n";
echo "2do bucle: $totalB \t10 (1er bucle) x 2 (su propio bucle) \n";
echo "3er bucle: $totalC \t10 (1er bucle) x 2 (2do bucle) x 3 (su propio bucle)";
```

**Salida:**

```
Primer bucle: 0 
     Segundo bucle: A 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
     Segundo bucle: B 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
Primer bucle: 1 
     Segundo bucle: A 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
     Segundo bucle: B 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
Primer bucle: 2 
     Segundo bucle: A 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
     Segundo bucle: B 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
Primer bucle: 3 
     Segundo bucle: A 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
     Segundo bucle: B 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
Primer bucle: 4 
     Segundo bucle: A 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
     Segundo bucle: B 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
Primer bucle: 5 
     Segundo bucle: A 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
     Segundo bucle: B 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
Primer bucle: 6 
     Segundo bucle: A 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
     Segundo bucle: B 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
Primer bucle: 7 
     Segundo bucle: A 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
     Segundo bucle: B 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
Primer bucle: 8 
     Segundo bucle: A 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
     Segundo bucle: B 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
Primer bucle: 9 
     Segundo bucle: A 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 
     Segundo bucle: B 
         Tercer bucle: X 
         Tercer bucle: Y 
         Tercer bucle: Z 

 --------------
TOTALES:
1er bucle: 10   10 (su propio bucle) 
2do bucle: 20   10 (1er bucle) x 2 (su propio bucle) 
3er bucle: 60   10 (1er bucle) x 2 (2do bucle) x 3 (su propio bucle)
```

### Observación final

Sea lo que sea que estés haciendo, en un contexto real los elementos no deberían repetirse/recorrerse indiscriminadamente (por ejemplo, en el tercer bucle hay sólo tres elementos, sin embargo el código está leyendo esos mismos tres elementos **¡60 veces!**). Para evitar eso tendrías que *normalizar*, creando por ejemplo arrays anidados u otro tipo de estructura donde leas los elementos sin incurrir en esta redundancia que será costosa no sólo en recursos, sino también en otros campos. Por ejemplo, si tus datos estuvieran en la nube y te cobran por elementos leídos, estarás pagando 60 lecturas en vez de 3. Esto puede ser una ruina si lo multiplicamos por varios miles o millones de usuarios accediendo a los datos.

Comment: Gente como tu se necesita en esta comunidad, aunque la pregunta suena un poco basica y redundante, en verdad tenia esta duda, y con esta respuesta me aclaraste todo. Gracias amigo !!

Comment: @IntruzO me alegro de que te haya servido. He agregado otros detalles a la respuesta, sobre todo para que consideres normalizar si fuera necesario.